# Inserting value from vba into html list

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, html-content-extraction

I have been able to manipulate data in a list using vba's .value method. But when trying to update a particular value it fills the value in as blank and won't let me change it. I'm trying to push a date into this field but the date is taken from a calendar next to the list which puts the date in the box from the calendar. When using dom explorer I just change the option value and it changes the date in the field. When I use the value method to change this same option it fills the field in blank. Any ideas?

[HTML code of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7gsE.png)

[Picture of list with calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm1gX.png)

I've been able to change the value using this:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")(27).Value = _
    "Today@javascript:gs.daysAgoStart(0)@javascript:gs.daysAgoEnd(0)"
```

To any value that is already in there, but can't change it to a date even though it accepts a date. For instance:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")(27).Value = "2016-11-04"
```

Leaves the list blank as if nothing is selected. Unless I enter a date that is already part of the list which pulls from the calendar, I can't change the date.

Comment: Use, the MS HTML Controls, and set an object of type IHTMLSelectElement to be the select 27, that you have.  Intellisense and locals should assist you then, I think the SelectedIndex needs to be set.  It could be a Jquery or custom calendar control, which has something else at heart that can be manipulated...

Answer (score 0):

To select option use `selectedIndex` property. To add new `option` element to `select` element create it with `doc.createElement("option")` first and then call `add` method on `select` element. HTH

```
Option Explicit

' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Sub NewOptionDemo()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim url As String

    url = "file:///c:/Temp/main.html"
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Dim htmlCombobox As MSHTML.HTMLSelectElement
    Set doc = ie.document
    Set htmlCombobox = doc.querySelector("select[id='select1']")

    If (htmlCombobox Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "No combobox with id 'select1' was found on the page."
    Else
        ' select first option
        htmlCombobox.selectedIndex = 0

        ' create new option, add this option to combobox and select it
        Dim newOption As HTMLOptionElement
        Set newOption = doc.createElement("option")
        newOption.Value = "new-option"
        newOption.Text = "New option"
        htmlCombobox.Add newOption
        htmlCombobox.selectedIndex = 3

        ' chnge value and text of first option and select it again
        htmlCombobox.Item(0).Value = "new-value-for-first-item"
        htmlCombobox.Item(0).Text = "new value for first item"
        htmlCombobox.selectedIndex = 0
    End If

    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

> main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>
<body>
    <select id="select1">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">2016-11-04</option>
        <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```